# When a Java system property is set on the command line without value ("-Dkey"), what value does it get?

Tags: java, command-line

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#CBBIJCHG), I can set system properties of a Java process on the command line with the following syntax:

```
-Dproperty=value
```

But what happens when I don't specify the value, i.e. when I omit the "equals value" part:

```
-Dproperty
```

What value will the system property be set to? `true`? An empty string? Or any string with an undefined, implementation specific value?

Comment: You can determine this by simply trying? Can’t you? If what you want is a formal definition, that's a different question. Maybe you should edit yours.

Comment: I'm not writing a Java program for myself, so I can't just try this out on all my user's VMs.

Comment: You don't need to try it on **all** JVMs. You just need to try it on **one**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is only the case if the behaviour of the one VM is due to a specification. It could also be an unspecified implementation detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will return an empty string. According to System.getProperty(String key) null is returned only if there is no property with that key. So if we define a propety with `-D` it exists in the system

Comment: Actually, the `getProperty` documentation only implies that the value is not `null`. But this is a useful piece of information - and probably the only thing that implementations checking for `-Dflag` flags should rely on.

Comment: @oberlies I agree, just better than nothing

Comment: In "Zulu11.37+17-CA", with `-Dflag`, the `System.getProperty("flag")` returns `null`.

Answer (score 4):

From simple trials with a Oracle HotSpot VM, I can see that system properties set on the command line without value get an **empty string** as value.

However this is only a partial answer to the question. A link to the some specification would be a better answer.